# getting error : Text String must be rendered within a <Text> component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am new to react Native , getting error

> Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a Text component.
>    .

I have not used text string other then textbox & button values  till now but getting is error

I am sharing my code below

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text , View } from 'react-native';
import { TextInput , Button  , Appbar} from 'react-native-paper';



class App extends React.Component {


  state  = {
    fanme : '',
    mname : ''
  }

  render(){

    return(

     <View style={styles.container}>

     <Appbar.Header><Appbar.Content title="Calculate lOVE%"/>  </Appbar.Header>

      <TextInput label='fname' />
      <TextInput label='mname'  />

      <Button style={{margin : 10}} icon="add-a-photo" mode="contained" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
    Calculate 
  </Button>


    </View>

    );
  }
}

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container : {
    flex : 1 ,
    backgroundColor : '#fff',
  },
});
```

Comment: Can you add error stack trace?

Comment: @RinkeshGolwala   
Invariant Violation: Nesting of <View> within <Text> is not currently supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In react-native button, use `title` property instead of button text:

```html
<Appbar.Header><Appbar.Content title="Calculate lOVE%"/></Appbar.Header>
<TextInput label='fname' />
<TextInput label='mname'  />
<Button title="Calculate" style={{margin : 10}} icon="add-a-photo" mode="contained" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}></Button>
```

More detail at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/button.html#title

Comment: I have fixed in your way but I am again getting same error

Comment: Try to remove all spaces between `Button` tag as my updated

Answer (score 0):

Here inside your Button component

```
<Button style={{margin : 10}} icon="add-a-photo" mode="contained" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
    Calculate // <-- ERROR
 </Button>
```

You put `Calculate` string, you could envolpe it with `<Text> Calculate </Text>` or use the native prop of button with `title="Clear button"` so your button component ends like this:

```
 <Button title="Calculate" style={{margin : 10}} icon="add-a-photo" mode="contained" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}/>
```

Comment: I have fixed in your way but I am again getting same error

Answer (score 0):

As React Native said texts should be rendered within Text Component!
Here is your problem:

```
<Button style={{margin : 10}} icon="add-a-photo" mode="contained" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
   Calculate 
</Button>
```

Should be change to:

```
<Button style={{margin : 10}} icon="add-a-photo" mode="contained" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}>
   <Text> Calculate </Text>
</Button>
```

Or use title prop for Button like this :

```
<Button title='Calculate' style={{margin : 10}} icon="add-a-photo" mode="contained" onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')} />
```